# Create new column, store value from another table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

This seems like a super easy task, but nothing seems to work.

In FCT General Ledger, there is a column named [EC_Value], every row contains the value 0 or 1.
If there is a matching Contract_FK, and the value in FCT General Ledger is 1, then I would like to have that value in DIM Contract as well.

These are the relevant tables with relevant columns:

**FCT General Ledger**

- *contract_fk
- EC_Value*

**DIM Contract**

- *Contract_PK*

I tried the following formulas to create the column in DIM Contract.

```
EC Included = 
VAR curValue = SELECTEDVALUE('DIM Contract'[Contract_PK])
VAR ecValue =
CALCULATE(
    SUM('FCT General Ledger'[EC_Value]), 
    FILTER('FCT General Ledger', 'FCT General Ledger'[contract_fk] = curValue )
)

RETURN
    IF(
        ecValue = 1,
        1,
        0
    )
```

This gives me a 0 in every row in DIM Contract.

```
EC Included = LOOKUPVALUE('FCT General Ledger'[EC_Value], 'FCT General Ledger'[contract_fk], 'DIM Contract'[Contract_pk])
```

This gives the following error message:
A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

```
EC Included = 
VAR curValue = SELECTEDVALUE('DIM Contract'[Contract_PK]) 

RETURN 

Calculate(MAX('FCT General Ledger'[EC_Value]),'FCT General Ledger'[contract_fk]= curValue)
```

This returns all blanks, and a 1 in only one row. So this seems to be the closest to the solution, but it only filled in the 1 at the row where the Contract_PK = 0.
I think this means I am not correctly using the SELECTEDVALUE method, because I might not iterating over every value.

Comment: First of all, why? 
Second, you need a calculated column, not a measure. Just use RELATED() or RELATEDTABLE()

Comment: @Pieter
I need this as a part of a bigger calculation that I am trying to make. For that calculation, I need to connect 9-10 tables to each other.

For that calculation, adding this information to 'DIM Contract' makes it a lot easier. I couldn't think of a way to connect the concerning calculation to FCT General Ledger.

I am sure that there are better ways of doing this, though.

Comment: 9-10 tables? Sounds like you don't have a star schema yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile, I came up with something that works.
There might be a cleaner solution out there, though. So feel free to correct me.

```
EC value = 
VAR curValue = VALUE ('DIM Contract'[Contract_PK]) 

RETURN 

Calculate(MAX('FCT General Ledger'[EC Value]),'FCT General Ledger'[contract_fk]= curValue)
```